# javascript static tests: jshint indentation customization

Tags: javascript, indentation, jshint

I've started using JSHint to statically test my JS code. There is a config option `indent` which defines the indentation that the code should follow. Everything is ok but the switch/case statements, especially when I have return statements inside. Is there any way to customize the jshint `indent` more than just declaring how many spaces are allowed per indent?

Unfortunately, the indentation desired by jshint is in conflict with the default indentation of my IDE (NetBeans in this case).

Comment: You can disable it so it does not do the check.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to disable it but to configure :)

Comment: No, there is no ability to configure that option further.

Comment: I agree that the suggested indentation of the case labels seems counter-intuitive and also in conflict with the default indentation of Visual Studio.  I've (begrudgingly) changed my code to match JSHint's recommendations on a recent project since the value of a clean (or at least not-quite-so-noisy) lint result outweighs the annoyance of the anomaly in formatting.

Comment: @CalebBell exactly the same as me...

Comment: Looks like the updated version with fixed indentation rules is coming ([see github](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/1228)). It's already fixed but not pushed to npm.